# Twilio Programmable SMS 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: twilio

I am currently using Twilio's programmable SMS to send and receive text messages, and I receive the text messages via a POST request from Twilio.  Recently, I have been getting batches of 502 errors that occur sporadically and last between 1 to 2 hours and then disappears.  I have gotten about 15 of these errors in the last 2 weeks.  I have spoken to my web hosting company, and they said that the errors are due to a relay block caused by a server being down at the ip address listed below.  The last error message I received is the following:

- 11210 HTTP bad host name
- 502 Bad Gateway
- An upstream server returned an invalid response
- X-Twilio-Reason Unknown host
- Transfer-Encoding chunked
- X-Cache MISS from ip-172-18-7-38.ec2.internal
- X-Cache-Lookup MISS from ip-172-18-7-38.ec2.internal:3128
- Content-Type text/html

I was told that the error is due to the server at 172.18.7.38 is down and is blocking communication between Twilio and my web host.  I have also received the same error message but with different ip addresses.  Here are the ip addresses from the other errors:

- X-Cache MISS from ip-172-18-21-71.ec2.internal
- X-Cache MISS from ip-172-18-11-49.ec2.internal
- X-Cache MISS from ip-172-18-7-38.ec2.internal
- X-Cache MISS from ip-172-18-8-108.ec2.internal

Could anyone please provide insight into this issue?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Twilio, and they told me that the problem was with DNS errors from GoDaddy.  I was using GoDaddy for my domain name, SSL, and web hosting.  After switching all 3 away from GoDaddy, I have not had any more 502 bad gateway errors.